# Smokestack simulation

Tags: smoke-simulation

I'm trying to simulate the smoke coming out of a smokestack. I have had some success using the quick smoke tool to create a vertically rising plume but I've been unsuccessful applying a wind force field to get it to travel horizontally after leaving a smokestack. I don't see how I can influence the force field to act horizontally with the quick smoke tool. When I turn on the wind force in the quick smoke options it seems to only allow vertical wind. Any insights would be appreciated.

Adding updated screen shot after first round of comments:

[image]

Comment: Where have you turned on the wind force in the quick smoke options? If a wind force field is created then you can rotate it. If there is no force field you can add it in Object mode with Shift+A, Force Field > Wind

Answer (score 0):

- Add Force Filed Object type Wind, rotate 90 deg
- Under Physics Properties set Strenght like 25

[image]

If you tried to affect smoke under *Smoke Domain properties Field Weight > Wind* ... it just saying how much Force Field object should affect domain.

[image]

Comment: Thanks, that helps me understand the purpose of some of the parameters. Still, when I create a wind force from the Add menu (Thanks Blunder) and rotate it and use the parameters shown by vklidu I still don't have the wind affecting the smoke. Do I need to somehow connect the wind and the smoke for the physics to work?

Comment: Have you baked the simulation after you added the force field? The Manta flow simulations (quick smoke, fluid, fire) require a lot of baking. Just noticed that it's not mentioned in vklidu's answer yet.

Comment: OK, I started from scratch and I don't know if it makes a difference but I created the wind forcefield first, then added the smoke domain and it worked. If the order that the objects are added is irrelevant that I probably got my self into a pile of incompatable options and just needed to start with a clean slate. Thanks to all for your advice.